# Removing white space from txt with python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, whitespace, shlex

I have a .txt file (scraped as pre-formatted text from a website) where the data looks like this:

```
B, NICKOLAS                       CT144531X       D1026    JUDGE ANNIE WHITE JOHNSON  
ANDREWS VS BALL                   JA-15-0050      D0015    JUDGE EDWARD A ROBERTS
```

I'd like to remove all extra spaces (they're actually different number of spaces, not tabs) in between the columns. I'd also then like to replace it with some delimiter (tab or pipe since there's commas within the data), like so:

```
ANDREWS VS BALL|JA-15-0050|D0015|JUDGE EDWARD A ROBERTS
```

Looked around and found that the best options are using regex or shlex to split. Two similar scenarios:

- [Python Regular expression must strip whitespace except between quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609596/python-regular-expression-must-strip-whitespace-except-between-quotes),
- [Remove white spaces from dict : Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152585/remove-white-spaces-from-dict-python).

Comment: Is there always more than one space between the data columns?

Comment: @cricket_007 yep, always more than one space

Comment: You shouldn't use regex, because the data might have 2 or more spaces in a column.  The data is in a text-table format, sp columns should be determined by the position of a character on each line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
s = """B, NICKOLAS                       CT144531X       D1026    JUDGE ANNIE WHITE JOHNSON  
ANDREWS VS BALL                   JA-15-0050      D0015    JUDGE EDWARD A ROBERTS
"""

# Update
re.sub(r"(\S)\ {2,}(\S)(\n?)", r"\1|\2\3", s)
In [71]: print re.sub(r"(\S)\ {2,}(\S)(\n?)", r"\1|\2\3", s)
B, NICKOLAS|CT144531X|D1026|JUDGE ANNIE WHITE JOHNSON  
ANDREWS VS BALL|JA-15-0050|D0015|JUDGE EDWARD A ROBERTS
```

Comment: It appends an extra pipe at the end.

Comment: Perfect! Clean and simple, plus it adds line breaks nicely.

Answer (score 7):

What about this?

```
your_string ='ANDREWS VS BALL                   JA-15-0050      D0015    JUDGE EDWARD A ROBERTS'
print re.sub(r'\s{2,}','|',your_string.strip())
```

Output:

```
ANDREWS VS BALL|JA-15-0050|D0015|JUDGE EDWARD A ROBERTS
```

Expanation:

I've used `re.sub()` which takes 3 parameter, a pattern, a string   you want to replace with and the string you want to work on.

What I've done is taking at least two space together , I 've replaced them with a `|` and applied it on your string.

Answer (score 7):

You can apply the regex `'\s{2,}'` (two or more whitespace characters) to each line and substitute the matches with a single `'|'` character.

```
>>> import re
>>> line = 'ANDREWS VS BALL                   JA-15-0050      D0015    JUDGE EDWARD A ROBERTS        '
>>> re.sub('\s{2,}', '|', line.strip())
'ANDREWS VS BALL|JA-15-0050|D0015|JUDGE EDWARD A ROBERTS'
```

Stripping any leading and trailing whitespace from the line before applying `re.sub` ensures that you won't get `'|'` characters at the start and end of the line.

Your actual code should look similar to this:

```
import re
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        subbed = re.sub('\s{2,}', '|', line.strip())
        # do something here
```

Comment: Thank you, really nicely explained. Just needed to add a linebreak function.

Answer (score 3):

Considering there are at least two spaces separating the columns, you can use this:

```
lines = [
'B, NICKOLAS                       CT144531X       D1026    JUDGE ANNIE WHITE JOHNSON  ',
'ANDREWS VS BALL                   JA-15-0050      D0015    JUDGE EDWARD A ROBERTS        '
]

for line in lines:
    parts = []
    for part in line.split('  '):
        part = part.strip()
        if part:  # checking if stripped part is a non-empty string
            parts.append(part)
    print('|'.join(parts))
```

Output for your input:

```
B, NICKOLAS|CT144531X|D1026|JUDGE ANNIE WHITE JOHNSON
ANDREWS VS BALL|JA-15-0050|D0015|JUDGE EDWARD A ROBERTS
```

Comment: Did your test it before posting as an answer?

Comment: How can this give `ANDREWS VS BALL|JA-15-0050|D0015|JUDGE EDWARD A ROBERTS`?

Comment: care to explain the downvote? @PeterWood Edited code gives the required output.

Comment: Basically you are creating a list with a whole bunch of `''` and skipping them with an if statement. Besides, `part.strip()` is called twice, once for comparing and once for appending two the list. IMHO, shorter code doesn't mean faster.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque where did I say that it is good solution?? And what's the point of becoming so offensive?? You have done yours with re, but I did w/o re, but it is still a solution.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ Sorry that you are hurt,I didn't really mean to. But you could see the points in updated comment. I think, it's logical. After optimising them, your answer could be great.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your data is in a "text-table" format.

I recommend using the first row to figure out the start point and length of each column (either by hand or write a script with regex to determine the likely columns), then writing a script to iterate the rows of the file, slice the row into column segments, and apply strip to each segment.

If you use a regex, you *must* keep track of the number of columns and  raise an error if any given row has more than the expected number of columns (or a different number than the rest). Splitting on two-or-more spaces will break if a column's value has two-or-more spaces, which is not just entirely possible, but also likely.  ***Text-tables like this aren't designed to be split on a regex, they're designed to be split on the column index positions.***

In terms of saving the data, you can use the csv module to write/read into a csv file.  That will let you handle quoting and escaping characters better than specifying a delimiter.  If one of your columns has a `|` character as a value, unless you're encoding the data with a strategy that handles escapes or quoted literals, your output will break on read.

Parsing the text above would look something like this (i nested a list comprehension with brackets instead of the traditional format so it's easier to understand):

```
cols = ((0,34),
        (34, 50),
        (50, 59),
        (59, None),
        )
for line in lines:
    cleaned = [i.strip() for i in [line[s:e] for (s, e) in cols]]
    print cleaned
```

then you can write it with something like:

```
import csv
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='|',
                            quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for line in lines:
        spamwriter.writerow([line[col_start:col_end].strip()
                             for (col_start, col_end) in cols
                             ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this library can solve this quite nicely:
http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/ascii/fixed_width_gallery.html#fixed-width-gallery

Impressive...